# What is the closure relation for multimode coherent state?

Tags: hilbert-space, coherent-states

How does the closure relation for multimode coherent state $| \{ \alpha_\lambda \} \rangle $ look like?

I suppose it should be some generalization of the closure relation for singlemode state $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int d^2\alpha~|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha | = \mathbb{1},$$ however, I was not able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it's just the same completeness relation for each wavelength? 
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int d^2\alpha_\lambda |\alpha_\lambda\rangle\langle\alpha_\lambda|= I$$